# If/else statement to display/hide image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, if-statement

The function should go like: if an integer value for a variable provided by a core module is larger than 0 then an image should be displayed, else it should remain hidden.

The Coremodule is constructed so if I in my `*.js` file write:
`data.truck.retarderBrake` (which is an integer). Then the coremodule will return the current `integervalue`.

So my "pseudo code" will look something like this:

```
if (data.truck.retarderBrake>0) {
    show.image ('images/RetarderON.png');
    } else {
    hide.image ('images/RetarderON.png');
}
```

In my HTML code I have a statement for the image:

```
    <div class="RetarderOn"></div>
```

and the CSS looks like this:

```
.RetarderOn {
  background-image: url("images/RetarderON.png");
  position: absolute;
  left: 851px;
  top: 13px;
  width: 92px;
  height: 71px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Can I do it this way? And what would the correct syntax for the JS if statement be. Maybe I can define all the properties of the image in the JS file instead of the CSS file?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `visibility` property for that specific element via its `style` object; you can find the element via [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) (if I assume there's only one of them), which accepts any valid CSS selector and returns the first match:

```
document.querySelector(".RetarderOn").style.visibility = data.truck.retarderBrake > 0 ? "visible" : "hidden";
```

If there are multiple matches, use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) and pick the relevant one from the resulting `NodeList`.